# What happens when I call "delete" on an uninitialized pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

Let's say I declare a pointer of char, and call delete on it without having called new. Can this cause a problem?

```
char* myptr;

if (condition)
    //do something involving myptr = new char[SIZE];
else
    //do something that doesnt involve myptr

//do more stuff
delete[] myptr;
```

I don't delete myptr under the if because another pointer in `//do more stuff` can point to it if `condition` was true. Obviously this works fine if `condition` was true because a "new" was called on `myptr`. Is deleting `myptr` bad if I entered the else condition, where `myptr` is unused?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's **undefined behavior**. The pointer **must** come from `new` or must be a null pointer.

Standard (N3797) 5.3.5`[expr.delete]`/2

> If the operand has a class type, the operand is converted to a pointer
>   type by calling the above-mentioned conversion function, and the
>   converted operand is used in place of the original operand for the
>   remainder of this section. **In the first alternative (delete object),
>   the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a
>   pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or
>   a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an
>   object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined.
>
>   [...]**

The part left out at the bottom is the same for `delete []`.

Deleting is only valid for

- null pointers
- pointers you got from new
- or a base class pointer pointing to the above.

---

### Null pointers:

To follow up on null pointers, calling `delete` on a null pointer is a noop and the pointer is still a null pointer afterwards (no need to reassign `nullptr` to it). This is guaranteed at least for the standard `delete` and deallocation functions. If you define custom ones you should also handle this properly.

Standard 5.3.5 `[expr.delete]`/7

> If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null pointer value, then:
>
> - **[...]**
>
> **Otherwise, it is unspecified whether the deallocation function will be called.** [ Note: The deallocation function is called regardless of whether the destructor for the object or some element of the array throws an
>   exception. — end note ]

So `delete` might do nothing at all or might call the deallocation function with the null pointer. Lets look at that function next:

Standard 3.7.4.2 `[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]`/3

> If a deallocation function terminates by throwing an exception, the behavior is undefined. **The value of the first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect.
>
>   [...]**

It is explicitly mentioned that it got no effect.

**Note:** If you define your own custom deallocation functions you should make sure you handle it the same way. Not handling null pointers properly would be evil.

Comment: If I initialize the pointer to null (`char* myptr = NULL;`) I can safely deleting it without adding an `if(myptr)` check, right?

Comment: @AndrewMpy yes, it's well defined and is a noop.

Answer (score 3):

If the pointer was initialised to `nullptr`, then deleting it would be safe.

As it stands, `myptr` is not initialised and attempting to delete it's value will likely cause a segmentation fault.

`char* myptr = nullptr` Will solve this issue in c++11 or later, or use `0` or `NULL` for c++98 or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It will be an undefined behavior . delete must be called on the pointer allocated memory using new.

However you can call delete on null pointer safely.

Answer (score 2):

you can write like

```
char* myptr=NULL;

if (condition)
    //do something involving myptr = new char[SIZE];
else
    //do something that doesnt involve myptr

//do more stuff
if(myptr)
  delete[] myptr;
```