# Declaring array in different scope in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I'm trying to declare array of objects of length specified in the file. Then i want to fill this array array with data from the same file.
Let's assume my file looks like that:
3 - length of the array
1 2
3 4
5 6
Here's my code

```
while ( getline (myfile,line) ){
istringstream ss(line);
if(i==0){
   ss >> numOfObjects;
   Object * array[numOfObjects];
} 
if((i>=i) && (i<=1+numOfObjects)){
   Object * o=new Object();
   ss >> x >> y;
   location l;
   l.x=x;
   l.y=y;
   o->setLocation(l);
   array[i-2]=o;
}
i++; 
}
```

When i try to run my code it's says that array was not declared in this scope. Is there anything I can do? I know it will work if I declare array outside of while loop but I need it has to be of exact length as specified in file.
Sorry if it is a silly question i'm just a beginner

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are a compiler extension. You should use a vector.

Comment: @Borgleader This, and it isn't declared in scope. More `new []` needed.

Comment: @Borgleader or create array by `new`

Comment: @NO_NAME That's a possibility, no way a recommendation :) ...

Comment: @NO_NAME Just because you could doesn't mean you should. I'm telling him what he should do ;)

Comment: You dont show how you initialize the variable `i` and then you are doing some very obscure things with it, `i>=i`is always true and `array[i-2]` tries to acces the -1st array element when `i=1,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ @Borgleader I don't know what is wrong with `new`. Of course he should should ensure that the table will be deleted, eg through the use of `std::unique_ptr`. `std::vector` is good when size of array changes at runtime. If it is not, you are free to choose.

Comment: @NO_NAME There's many things wrong with `new`/`new[]` for the average use case. It's an advanced thing to use (and consider).

Answer (score 1):

You could declare it outside and dynamically allocate memory using new after.

```
Object * array = nullptr;
if (...)
{
 ....
 array = new Object[numOfObjects];
 ....
}

delete [] array;
```

As pointed out, you should consider using a vector, which automatically manage their memory

Comment: Uninitialized pointer can be deleted in the example. Initialize it with `nullptr` and put `if (array == nullptr)` before `delete[]`.

Comment: @NO_NAME thanks for pointing it out, but no need to check it before `delete` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133056/what-happens-when-i-call-delete-on-an-uninitialized-pointer-in-ca

Answer (score 0):

Read the number of things outside the loop, not as a special case inside it.

```
if (getline(myfile,line))
{
   istringstream number(line);
   number >> numOfObjects;
   Object * array[numOfObjects];

   while (i < numOfObjects && getline (myfile,line))
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```